# Как реализовать навигацию по каталогу на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Нужно реализовать навигацию по каталогу папок с помощью Java Script. Так сказать, обычный, примитивный эмулятор файлового менеджера (без файлов, загрузок, сохранения и т д - только лишь пустые папки). То есть с возможностью зайти во внутренние папки, а так же вернуться назад (так же как работает Total Commander) Достаточно 2 уровней вложенности для наглядности. Как можно это реализовать наиболее простым способом?

Comment: С помощью кода на JavaScript, конечно же. Вы что-то пытались уже сделать или хотите готовое решение?

Comment: Вот решение на чиcтом ES6, мало ли, пригодится кому:
https://jsbin.com/nehafe/3/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: @11111000000 Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответов.

Answer (score 1):

Вот простой паттерн решения (ES6, сделал [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/nehafe/9/edit?html,css,js,output)):

1. Данные (Model)

   ```
   let data = {
     folder1: {
       'folder2': {
         'file.txt': 'some content',...
   , path = []
   ```
2. Интерфейс (View)

   ```
   template = data => {
       if(isObject(data)) {
           return Object.keys(data).reduce(((html,it) => html  + `<my-file class="type-${isObject(data[it]) ? 'folder' : 'file'}">${it}</my-file>`),'');
       } else {
           return `<div>${data}</div>`;
       }
   },

   render = folder => document.body.innerHTML = (path.length > 0 ? '<my-file>..</my-file>' : '') + template(folder);
   ```
3. Обработка событий (Controller)

   ```
   window.addEventListener('click',  (event) => {

       let node = event.target;

       if(node.tagName === 'MY-FILE') {

           if(node.textContent == '..')
               path.pop();
           else
               path.push(node.textContent);

           let folder = path.reduce((tree,name) => tree[name], data);
           render(folder);
       }
   });

   render(data);
   ```